Finding a function for the number of people on a bus
I've been trying to pin down the function that would describe the number of people on an ideal bus ( # of stops and passengers approaches infinity/ is large enough that the function is continuous), where a random number of people get on the bus at each stop and everyone has a randomly selected stop where they get off (after the stop they got on, of course). I've made simulations, and I got a curve on a graph, but I don't have a clue how I'd get an equation out of it. Here are the graphs (gray are the actual runs; red is the average/what I'm trying to get the equation for; x-axis is percent of journey; y-axis is the number of people * some constant):
Graph with all of the runs
(and only the red curve):
Resulting curve
Here is the code that generates the curves, the function is the result of averaging a ton of these toghether:
 bus = []
    data = []
    for current_stop in range(NUM_STOPS+1):
        if not (current_stop == NUM_STOPS or current_stop == 0): # nobody can enter the bus in the first and last stops
            for i in range(random.randint(0, MAX_PEOPLE_PER_STOP)):
                p = Person(random.randint(current_stop+1, NUM_STOPS))
                bus.append(p)
        
        bus[:] = [x for x in bus if not leaving(x, current_stop)] #have all people with said stop listed leave the bus
        data.append(len(bus))

```


What is your question?
